# Communicating Browser Extension and external application

Tags: browser, ipc

I'm trying to connect a browser extension (Firefox, Chrome, IE...) with an external application. Using a non-polling system to notify the messages between the components.

I've already seen several approaches, but I'm not sure which ones are possible and which ones are the best.

One solution could be trying to use a IPC (Os-dependant) solution, as named pipes or sockets, but I'm not sure if I can open a named pipe in a firefox or chrome extension. Moreover, I don't know if there are any "event based" system not to need polling as a mechanism for handling the communication.

The other solution (only if I use firefox) is to use XPCOM, I think with this approach, I should instantiate a XPCOM component, implemented in the browser extension, from the External Application. I think should need the XPCOM thing as a dependency in my External Application, right?

But, using this method, is it possible to handle the communication in a asynchronous way?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Since the rapid release schedule for FireFox, it's warmly recommended to move away from XPCOM and use js-ctypes to make calls to binary modules. I've been trying this out, but indeed the asynchronous thing and calling something *onto* nsIThread's on FireFox from outside may be tricky. I'm about to try named pipes and  nsIFileInputStream/nsIFileOutputStream, but am not sure it'll work.